# How to fill forms with AJAX - using node express

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, mongoose

I understand that I can update a part of the page using AJAX, without refreshing the page. How can I achieve that correctly?

```
//Get Book
router.get('/form/:id', (req, res) => { 
  Book.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
  })
    .then(books=> {
      res.send(books)
      });
    });
});
```

Where I want to add e.g. title via AJAX.

```
     <div class="form-group">
         <b class="titleclass">Title:</b>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
     </div>
```

### My attempt:

```
//Get Book
router.get('/form/', (req, res) => { 
  var x="this is title";
  res.send(x)
});
```

JS:

```
   $(".test").click(function () {       
        $.get("/form/", function (data, status) {
            alert(data); //does not trigger               
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send title like this.you must use return false like preventDefault() in ajax.not /form/ true is /form **edited**:

```
$(.test).click(function(){//and get title with ajax in html file
$.get("/form", function(data, status){
    alert(data)
})return false;});

router.get('/form', (req, res) => { var x="this is title"; res.send(x)});
app.use(function(req, res) {//if not requested from same server
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); });
```

Comment: I can't make it work, did I do it wrong with url at `$.get("/form/"`? I updated my answer with my code, under "My attempt".

Answer (score 0):

Per jQuery docs, $.get function callback is executed if the request succeeds. Please make sure you're not dealing with CORS issues. If the case add these to your response header:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept");
```

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of things I see as possible issues here:

1. You aren't passing in a :id parameter in your GET.
2. You should remove the trailing slash in `/form/`.
3. Your response should be `res.json({books: books});`.
4. Enable CORS, if not requested from the same server.

I hope this helps.